# How to automatically put the footnotes before punctuation?

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, l3regex

I have little problem :). I have a big file with 1422 footnotes. The problem is that I need to put every footnotes before punctuation (**.,;**).

How to automatically put the footnotes before punctuation?

THX a lot.

Vitaliano

Comment: Your request contradicts: "I need to put [...] after" versus "How to put [...] before"

Comment: correct. I'm sorry

Comment: Not a “little problem”, I'm afraid, if you want to solve it on the TeX side. Use your text editor and its regular expressions facilities.

Comment: i tried to use this: ([\,\.\:\;])(\\footnote\{[^\}^\n]*\}) with \2\1, but if in the footnote there are textit, textbf or other command this expression dont work. I need find a solution to capture group of footnote. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how brave you want to be with regular expressions you could match footnote for any fixed depth of nested `{}` groups, however simpler is just change

```
  .\footnote
```

to

```
  \myfootnote.
```

And similarly for the other punctuation characters.

Then as long as you haven't used the optional argument `\footnote[]{..}` form all you need is a simple

```
 \newcommand\myfootnote[2]{\footnote{#2}#1}
```

Then

```
\myfootnote.{the \textbf{footnote}}
```

will expand to

```
\footnote{the \textbf{footnote}}.
```

If you need to support

```
\myfootnote.[2]{the footnote for mark 2}
```

It's just a bit more complicated as `\newcommand` doesn't directly allow definition of optional second argument.

Comment: I love a good hack.  +1

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `s/a good hack/an elegantly engineered solution/`

Comment: Thx a lot. I love this. And special thx to all members of this great forum :).